# handleChange event does not match the data in local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a select to select languages, when I get the value / code from select the language I save it into localstorage then I take the value / language code from the localstorage I take and I throw it as a parameter for hit 1 API for example API 'pages', to get all language according to the value / language code thrown in local storage, after successfully getting a response from the API 'pages', then I store the response in local storage for me to take and display as needed, but why when I enter data from local storage into state, the response doesn't match localstorage?

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      language:[],
      code:'',
      pages:[],
      loading:true
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(){
    if(this.refs.selectLanguage){
      const result = this.refs.selectLanguage.value
      this.setState({
        code:result
      })
      this.props.resSave('lang-code', result)
    }

    //code language from localstorage will send to API 'pages-content'
    const getCodeFromLocal = this.props.resGet('lang-code')

    Api.post('pages-content', {CODE:getCodeFromLocal})
    .then((response) =>{
      if(response.data.STATUS_CODE === '200'){
        this.props.resSave('toLocalPages' , JSON.stringify(response.data.DATA))
      }
    })

  }

async componentDidMount(){
    await Api.get('language')
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.data.STATUS_CODE === '200'){
        this.setState({
          language:response.data.DATA,
          pages:JSON.parse(this.props.resGet('toLocalPages')),
          loading:false
        })
      }
    })
  }

render() {
    const {language,loading,pages} = this.state

    if(loading){
      return(
        <p>loading...</p>
      )
    }else{
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Form.Group controlId="selectLanguage">
            <Form.Label><b>{this.state.pages.page_login.subtitle}</b></Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="select" ref="selectLanguage" onChange={this.handleChange}>
              <option>--select--</option>
              {language.map(data => {
                return(
                  <React.Fragment key={data.language_id}>
                    <option value={data.code}>{data.language_name}</option>
                  </React.Fragment>
                )
              })}
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }
  }
```

I've tried several times, when I change language and I check on localstorage it works fine, but when I want to retrieve the data to be displayed in the UI / view it doesn't work, is the way I'm doing it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

```
  async componentDidMount(){
     let response =  await Api.get('language');
     let data= await response.json();

     this.setState({
          language:data,
          pages:JSON.parse(this.props.resGet('toLocalPages')),
          loading:false
        })  

  }


 async handleChange(){
    if(this.refs.selectLanguage){
      const result = this.refs.selectLanguage.value
      this.setState({
        code:result,
        loading:true;
      });
      this.props.resSave('lang-code', result)
    }
    //code language from localstorage will send to API 'pages-content'
    const getCodeFromLocal = this.props.resGet('lang-code')
    let response = await Api.post('pages-content', {CODE:getCodeFromLocal});
    let data= await response.json();
    this.props.resSave('toLocalPages' , JSON.stringify(data))
    this.setState({

        loading:false;
      });
  }
```

Comment: What you mean delayed?

Comment: so when I do an event change, I send the value of select to send as a parameter, then if the status is successful I save the data into local storage, then I save the data that I take back for use on other pages for example, home, about etc.

Comment: Can you set loading to true in handleChange()

Comment: And Api.post('pages-content', {CODE:getCodeFromLocal}) .then((response) =>{ to false

Comment: where to store data other than localstorage where else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200584/discussion-between-oleg-and-muhamad-rahmat-setiawan).

Comment: I am waiting for pass

Comment: I have a new problem

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: so the initial problem like this, I have a component Select the language that is imported into the incoming component, from this compilation language component onChange I hit one API then I enter the response from the API into local storage, compile I take data from local storage to be moved in the component login and enter into the state login component, this data is not updated like local storage, but if the local storage of data is updated successfully, how does the state update in the life cycle react?

Comment: Can you post new question